# Python bs4 extracting the right table content

Tags: beautifulsoup

i am struggling with this problem now for some time and need some help. I reach out to the website "https://www.finanzen.net/boersenkurse" and want to extract the table whoch is the part "Meistgesuchte Aktien". As there are some  iun the document, i am getting also the other tables, which i am not interested in.

I want to create a Dataframe out of the data. So each row shoul look the same as on the website. Means that Name = SAP, Kurs 96,33, ect.

```
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
URL = "https://www.finanzen.net/boersenkurse"
html = requests.get(URL, {}).text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all("tr")
tables
'''
```

I do noct get how to choose only the relevant tr. If someone has any idea, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://www.finanzen.net/boersenkurse"
table = soup.find_all("table", class_="table-overflow-hidden")[1]

#Extracting heading of the columns of the table.

rows = table.find_all('tr')
columns=[]
headings = rows[0].find_all('th')
for col in headings:
    columns.append(col.text.strip())
print(columns)

#Extracting all data of the table row wise.

all_data=[]
for row in rows[1:]:
    data = row.find_all('td')
    lst=[]
    for d in data:
        lst.append(d.text.strip())
    all_data.append(lst)

 #Creating the dataframe out of the extracted data.

ds = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=columns)
ds
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Easier to use pandas and index in for table

```
import pandas as pd 

pd.read_html('https://www.finanzen.net/boersenkurse')[2]
```

soup still using pandas at end:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas

r = requests.get('https://www.finanzen.net/boersenkurse')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
t = soup.select_one('div:nth-child(4) table')
pd.DataFrame([[i.text.strip() for i in r.select('th,td')] for r in t.select('tr')])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn’t think about this way. If anyone else has an answer regarding the bs4 problem, i would love to hear it.

Comment: you could grab table with soup.select('div:nth-child(4) table') then loop tr within

Comment: Thanks you. When i try to run your bs4 code, i get an error: NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: you need a later version of bs4. Upgrade to latest as you get access to much more functionality. Just using pandas will be more efficient than using pandas and beautifulsoup.

Comment: you can possibly also just switch nth-child to nth-of-type in this case without an upgrade. Not tested.